# Datagridview in winforms application updated automatically when there is any change in database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, ef-code-first

I am working on a winforms c# application which is using the technologies like Entity Frame work-code first.i have to make a form in which records from database continuously should shown.first i apply a simple timer technique which updates Grid and other control after 5 sec. but it is too much expensive and eat resources.

i want to ask is there any other sophisticated method by which data in DGV and other controls automatically updated if any change happen in Database.

Comment: +! for good question. You could've maybe google'd this first, but I suppose your topic and reason for looking to other alternatives is all valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring

Look into SQLDependency. It is designed for this exact scenario.

There is a DataChanged event handler.

I used it very recently on a project for showing 'live' data from our TFS server and it's working very well.

Comment: it seems nice solution .sorry my points are very low so i can give you +1

Comment: another lazy question is SQLDependency work with Entity framework Code first?

Comment: They can co-exist in any solution, yes. They serve different purposes but can both work together in a data layer nicely: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/496484/SqlDependency-with-Entity-Framework-5-0